# Visual studio cannot open input file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to build this project in my VS2015 https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi . The build fails in pthread.h - struct redifinition error (starts on line 322). So i tried temporary commenting these lines (though i'm not sure that it wouldn't break something else) and now am getting an error `cannot open input file 'libcurl.x86.lib'`. The lib itself is not referenced explicitly anywhere, so where should i put it in order to fix that?

Comment: Pthreads are normally associated with Linux . Are you sure you are not building the Linux implementation of this project?

Comment: The windows branch has the same sources, and i'm trying to build it from the VS via SLN file provided in the porject, so it is at least meant to work, thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 3):

Your first error, struct redinfition is due to the redefinition of struct timespec.  You most likely have it defined somewhere in your system files. To find out exactly where go struct timespec and right click "goto definition". You will see where the second of definition of timespec is on your system.

To resolve this problem add _TIMESPEC_DEFINED to your preprocessor definition. You can then remove the comments out of those lines.

Your next error - cannot open input file 'libcurl.x86.lib is due to the fact that this lib is not included with your source and it is not being build.  Doing a search of all the project files I found libcurl.x64.lib along with some other 64 bit libs.  I suggest you change your build configuration to x64 to build with these libraries.  (Looks like the project is supposed to be built in 64-bit mode).

Good luck.